# Can you use eDismax without using Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax

My application uses Lucene 4.1 and provides two different search syntaxes, the standard query parser syntax and an approximation of dismax search that Solr has. Solr now has the eDismax search that combines the two, that would be perfect for my application so I could provide a single interface that supports both syntaxes.

But is eDismax available within latest versions of Lucene as I have no requirement/desire to rewrite my code for Solr ?

Comment: Did you mean "Can you use edismax _without_ using Solr"?

Comment: @fiskfisk oops yes I did, now changed !

Comment: the answer to this question is more than likely : unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

The current implementation of EDisMax ties into certain Solr features, so it would probably require a bit of a rewrite to yank out the related parts. You can see the implementation (for 4.7.0) on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/4.7.0/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.java/) (for easier navigation) (or [Apache Lucene SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.java) for current trunk).

[SOLR-2368](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2368) is the original issue that tracked the implementation and is a good place to start digging for implementation specific details.

Comment: Suprised with new versions of Solr and Lucene being released together that they have done it this way.

Comment: What Solr only features is it tied to ?

Comment: If you follow the link in the post til "Apache Lucene SVN", you'll see the current version. The imports from org.apache.solr are the features it depends on from the Solr repository.